# Глобальная переменная JS

Tags: ajax, javascript

Есть такой код:

```
loadContent = {

  limitAjax: 0,

  start: function (btn) {
     console.log(this.limitAjax); // not equal 4
     // Ajax response
     this.limitAjax = response.limit; //  response.limit = 4
  }
}
```

Ajax возвращает новое значение лимит, которое назначается для `this.limitAjax`. Но при следующем вызове функции значение `this.limitAjax` по-прежнему = 0.

Делать переменную суперглобальное - не хочется...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы проверите свой кусок кода без Ajax, то он будет абсолютно нормально работать:

```
loadContent = {
  limitAjax: 0,

  start: function (btn) {
     this.limitAjax = 4; 
  }
}

loadContent.start();
console.log(loadContent.limitAjax); //Вывод: 4
```

Поэтому весь вопрос в том, как вы там этот Ajax используете. Либо вы не учитываете, что Ajax асинхронный, либо, скорее всего, неправильно используете области видимости при возвращении результата. Но поскольку Вы решили этот очень важный фрагмент кода не приводить, указать на конкретную ошибку не получится.

Answer (score 1):

[@Jony](/users/18030/jony), вообще хотелось бы видеть, как вы вызываете функцию (и что такое this в ней), но в целом js-подход к статичным переменным подразумевает замыкания:

```
start: (function() {
    var limit = 0;
    return function () {
        // тело этой функции будет видеть limit, а весь остальной мир - нет
    };
})(),
```